# How to show multiple Pushpins in same coordinates in bingmap?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my application I want to plot multiple locations in bing map.In some cases some locations are same so they have same lattitude and longtitude. Because of having same lattitude and longtitude .these locations only one location is showing on the map.But I want to show these locations on the map separately.Please anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

You may cluster pushpins which have same (or similar) lat/long, check this [article](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/11/pushpin-clustering-with-the-windows-phone-7-bing-map-control/) about clustering pushpins

Comment: dead link, just goes to the guys blog.